# HgWebDir push permission denied error

Tags: mercurial

I have a new Fedora 12 server that I am attempting to set up Mercurial on. I have `yum install`ed mercurial, and most things seem to work fine. However, after setting up hgwebdir.cgi through apache, I am unable to do an `hg push` to the only repo currently being hosted. The error I get back is:

```
searching for changes
abort: HTTP Error 500: Permission denied: .hg/store/lock
```

httpd is running as user apache

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      1691     1  0 13:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1694  1691  0 13:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1695  1691  0 13:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1696  1691  0 13:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1697  1691  0 13:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1698  1691  0 13:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1699  1691  0 13:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1700  1691  0 13:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1701  1691  0 13:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

and I set permissions so that the apache user owns the whole repo and everything. In a last ditch attempt, I even made the repo globally writable.

```
[root@builds .hg]# ll
total 424K
drwxrwxrwx.  3 apache apache 4.0K 2010-04-19 14:43 .
drwxrwxrwx. 19 apache apache 4.0K 2010-04-15 13:33 ..
-rw-rw-rw-.  2 apache apache   57 2010-04-13 11:42 00changelog.i
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 apache apache   93 2010-04-16 15:33 branchheads.cache
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 apache apache 192K 2010-04-15 13:33 dirstate
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache  156 2010-04-19 14:43 hgrc
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 apache apache   42 2010-04-15 13:33 last-message.txt
-rw-rw-rw-.  2 apache apache   23 2010-04-13 11:42 requires
drwxrwxrwx.  4 apache apache 4.0K 2010-04-19 11:26 store
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 apache apache   45 2010-04-14 14:08 tags.cache
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 apache apache    7 2010-04-16 15:33 undo.branch
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 apache apache 192K 2010-04-16 15:33 undo.dirstate
[root@builds .hg]# cd store
[root@builds store]# ll
total 308K
drwxrwxrwx.  4 apache apache 4.0K 2010-04-19 11:26 .
drwxrwxrwx.  3 apache apache 4.0K 2010-04-19 14:43 ..
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 apache apache  20K 2010-04-16 15:33 00changelog.i
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 apache apache  81K 2010-04-16 15:33 00manifest.i
drwxrwxrwx. 17 apache apache 4.0K 2010-04-13 11:47 data
drwxrwxrwx.  3 apache apache 4.0K 2010-04-13 11:43 dh
-rw-rw-rw-.  2 apache apache 177K 2010-04-15 11:03 fncache
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 apache apache   67 2010-04-16 15:33 undo
```

I have a clone of the repo elsewhere on the machine running as a different user. If I set the the `default` value in the `[paths]` section of the clones hgrc file to the local filepath on the server, the push works fine, but if I switch it to use the url, I get the error every time.

Some possible quirks in how I've set this up... hgwebdir.cgi is sitting in `/var/www/cgi-bin` and the repo is a child of `/opt/hg`. I turned off suexec as well, and this doesn't seem to clear up the issue. The only line I added in the apache config to get hgwebdir running is:

```
ScriptAlias /hg "/var/www/cgi-bin/hgwebdir.cgi"
```

The hgweb.config is also in `/var/www/cgi-bin` and it's contents are:

```
[collections]
/opt/hg = /opt/hg

[trusted]
users = *

[web]
baseurl = /hg
push_ssl = false
allow_push = *
```

The repo browser is working fine, it's just push that doesn't work. Apache error_log doesn't have anything in about this error at all.

Answer (score 15):

For me it was the permissions were set wrong on the server. A `chown -R www-data /path/to/repo` (on the server) fixed it all up for me... maybe this is different for you. 
Good luck.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu. The problem stopped when I loosened the permissions on the `.hg` directory.

I did a `chmod -R 777 .hg` from the repo directory. After that, everything worked. I still need to play around to find the minimally permissive option that permits pushes, but this works on our internal dev server.

Comment: I don't like so much giving 777 permissions to files, but it solved my problem on first attempt. Now I'll try to understand which permissions were wrong. Btw, +1 for me.

Comment: I also had this problem, but instead of giving 777, I investigated that certain files/folders in .hg/ AND in the working directory were owned by another user than `www-data`. So I changed them to `www-data` as that is the user hgweb.cgi is running as.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of 777, with the webserver running under the group `apache`, and your repositories in `/opt/hg`:

Execute `sudo chown :apache /opt/hg -R` to add the repositories to the apache group and  `sudo chmod g+w /opt/hg -R` to give write access to the group. This way you just give enough permissions.

BTW under Ubuntu the apache process runs under `www-data` instead of `apache`.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear to me that the repo is locked from the first auth, in wich it gets the changesets.
After getting the chagesets hg tries to authenticate again while, i suppose, the repo is still locked
Hg autehticates 3 times before failing (autenticação http: usuário goolic, senha **************)

```
hg push https://versoes.solidarp.com.br/hgweb.wsgi/home/solidarp/public_repos/profile_andre --verbose --debug
using https://versoes.solidarp.com.br/hgweb.wsgi/home/solidarp/public_repos/profile_andre
sending between command
autorização http requerida
domínio: soliDARP
usuário: goolic
senha: 
autenticação http: usuário goolic, senha **************
enviando revisões para https://versoes.solidarp.com.br/hgweb.wsgi/home/solidarp/public_repos/profile_andre
sending capabilities command
autenticação http: usuário goolic, senha **************
capabilities: changegroupsubset lookup pushkey unbundle=HG10GZ,HG10BZ,HG10UN stream=65537 branchmap
sending heads command
autenticação http: usuário goolic, senha **************
procurando por mudanças
common changesets up to 000000000000
7 revisões encontradas
list of changesets:
3d58879c5dcc778704134804de35b0441412cb0f
a3e6697fa72c9a4e06030b61a84bd2a00427f26f
481ce6a7f0c58ed5b838fc86d1b93af6b857eaf1
afed11efb8e2716675a7a39baf3b8b57c8740f44
ba4d9574fd84311d3b894aea39e8338ad3b242cd
aea9b49b6a933a11d4801d0dbab0e5b07d70b2d2
9c1757572d3bac793332999e6966b1135bfaf844
empacotando mudanças: 0 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 1 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 2 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 3 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 4 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 5 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 6 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 7 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 8 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 9 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 10 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 11 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 12 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 13 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 14 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 15 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 16 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 17 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 18 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 19 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 20 trechos
empacotando mudanças: 21 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 0 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 1 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 2 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 3 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 4 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 5 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 6 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 7 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 8 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 9 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 10 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 11 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 12 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 13 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 14 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 15 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 16 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 17 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 18 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 19 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 20 trechos
empacotando manifestos: 21 trechos
empacotando arquivos: .project 0 trechos
empacotando arquivos: .project 1 trechos
empacotando arquivos: .project 2 trechos
empacotando arquivos: .project 3 trechos
empacotando arquivos: .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs 4 trechos
empacotando arquivos: .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs 5 trechos
empacotando arquivos: .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs 6 trechos
empacotando arquivos: .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs 7 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Busao.java 8 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Busao.java 9 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Busao.java 10 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Busao.java 11 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Busao.java 12 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Busao.java 13 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Busao.java 14 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Busao.java 15 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Busao.java 16 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Busao.java 17 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Cidade.java 18 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Cidade.java 19 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Cidade.java 20 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Cidade.java 21 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Cidade.java 22 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Cidade.java 23 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Cidade.java 24 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Cidade.java 25 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Cidade.java 26 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Cidade.java 27 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Cidades.java 28 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Cidades.java 29 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Cidades.java 30 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Cidades.java 31 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 32 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 33 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 34 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 35 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 36 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 37 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 38 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 39 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 40 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 41 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 42 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 43 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 44 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 45 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 46 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 47 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 48 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 49 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 50 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 51 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 52 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Controle.java 53 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Interface.java 54 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Interface.java 55 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Interface.java 56 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Interface.java 57 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Interface.java 58 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Interface.java 59 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Interface.java 60 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Interface.java 61 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Interface.java 62 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Interface.java 63 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Interface.java 64 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Interface.java 65 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Interface.java 66 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Linha.java 67 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Linha.java 68 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Linha.java 69 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Linha.java 70 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Linha.java 71 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Linha.java 72 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Linha.java 73 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Linha.java 74 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Linha.java 75 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Linha.java 76 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Passagem.java 77 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Passagem.java 78 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Passagem.java 79 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Passagem.java 80 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Passagem.java 81 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Passagem.java 82 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Passagem.java 83 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Passagem.java 84 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Passagem.java 85 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Passagem.java 86 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Passagem.java 87 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Passagem.java 88 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Passagem.java 89 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Viagem.java 90 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Viagem.java 91 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Viagem.java 92 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Viagem.java 93 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Viagem.java 94 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Viagem.java 95 trechos
empacotando arquivos: src/Transporte/Viagem.java 96 trechos
sending unbundle command
sending 6254 bytes
autenticação http: usuário goolic, senha **************
abortado: HTTP Error 500: Permission denied: .hg/store/lock
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an selinux issue.

I just got through the same issue

try this as root

echo 0> /selinux/enforce

and try again.   that will disable selinux until reboot so to fix it permanently you will need to disable selinux or figure out how to disable this specific issue

here is where I found the solution

http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/Push-Denied-hg-store-lock-FC12-https-ldap-wsgi-td814854.html

selinux disabling info here

http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html

Answer (score 0):

Got to this thread trying to solve a similar error, on a slightly different setup (ubuntu, cgi file in the repositry base). 
Long story short I had 2 major issues:

- I ended up removing the baseurl option
- options in hgrc and in hgweb.config do not seem to be always handled the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation to @pete-brumm, but becasue I will be transitioning to a controlled region later, turning off SELinux isn't an option.

Turn SELinux off like Pete say and retry the action - if it works, you've isolated the issue. Turn it back on like this:

```
# echo 1> /selinux/enforce
```

Before turning SELinux off completely, try changing the security context where your repos are located:

```
# chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/repo
```

Answer (score 0):

One other possibility for those searching these archives.

I was running a WSGIDaemonProcess from apache, like so:

```
  WSGIScriptAlias /hg /srv/www/hg/wsgiapp.py
  WSGIDaemonProcess hgserve display-name=%{GROUP} user=hgrepo group=hgrepo \
                  threads=10 maximum-requests=1000 \
                  processes=2 umask=0007 inactivity-timeout=300
  WSGIProcessGroup hgserve
```

So, in my case, the user:group owning the files in the repo should've been hgrepo:hgrepo, and, indeed, I had this right.  Yet, sure enough, a quick experimental chmod 0777 revealed that the problem was somehow a standard ownership/permissions problem.  Well, it turns out that I had *another* WSGIDaemonProcess in the apache config, for a different purpose altogether, pointing to a different location, and assigned a different processGroup, user, and group.  Nevertheless, this (above) WSGIDaemonProcess was running as that *other* user:group, and, so, of course, it wasn't working.  For now, I've just removed that other process, as it was only experimental anyway, but, fwiw, here's one for the archives.